# How do stop elements from changing (properties) during JavaScript events?

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I'm currently making a "Drag and Drop" engine in JavaScript. When I pick up an element to move it, the cursor changes from `cursor: move` (which I set in the CSS) to `cursor: text` which I don't want. It also can select (highlight) text from other elements while I move the drag-object around which (again) I don't want. How do I prevent these issues from happening?

```
// JavaScript Document

var posX;
var posY;
var element;
var currentPos;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", drag, false);

function drag(event) {
    if(event.target.className == "square") {
        element = event.target;
        currentPos = findPos(element);
        posX = event.clientX -currentPos.x; //-parseInt(element.offsetLeft);
        posY = event.clientY -currentPos.y; //-parseInt(element.offsetTop);
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
    }
}

function move(event) {

    if (typeof(element.mouseup) == "undefined")
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
    //Prevents redundantly adding the same event handler repeatedly
    
    element.style.left = event.clientX - posX + "px";
    element.style.top = event.clientY - posY + "px";
}

function drop() {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
    //alert("DEBUG_DROP");
}

function findPos(obj) { // Donated by `lwburk` on StackOverflow
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.square {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    cursor:move;
}

p {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    outline-style: dotted;
    outline-color: #000;
    outline-width: 1px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<p class="square">Thing One</p>
<p class="square">Thing Two</p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey,
to prevent the highlighting you can use CSS:

```
* {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

To prevent default actions (which may be the cause of your cursor change?) in the event handler put

```
event.preventDefault()
```

where event is your event (passed to the handler).  You could also try setting the CSS attribute in the event handler:

```
event.target.setAttribute("style","cursor: move;");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="square" ondragstart="return false" onselectstart="return false">Thing One</p>
```